# Why are certain cells more likely to be attacked in autoimmune conditions?

Tags: cell-biology, immunology, autoimmune

For example, type 1 diabetes occurs when the immune system attacks and kills beta cells in the pancreas. This is relatively common.

What makes beta cells more likely to be targeted than, say, alpha cells in the pancreas?

Answer (score 2):

Autoimmune reactions each have their target [antigens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antigen). They'll "attack" wherever those antigens are expressed. In the case of Type 1 diabetes, many *specific* antigens [have been identified](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3312399/), and they all correspond to regions on the surface of pancreatic islet β cells. Ultimately, however, the immune reaction is targeting [proinsulin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proinsulin) and its processed product [insulin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulin), which are produced by solely by β cells. [This](https://diabetes.diabetesjournals.org/content/54/suppl_2/S87) is an interesting review covering the topic.